# how to change href of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdown menu that when i click on it open sub-menu and when click on anywhere(also on it) it close.
i want when this menu is open change href from # to own page that when i click on it dosn't close menu instead open a new page.
sorry for bad explain.
this is what in my mind:

```
$('body').on('click',(function(){
        $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
        $('.dropdown a').attr('href','#');
        $('.dropdown a').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
  });   
$('.dropdown').on('click' ,function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(".open").on("click", function(){
        $('.dropdown a').attr('href','http://example.com');
                $('.dropdown a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
    });
});
```

i also try this but dosn't work fine

```
$('body').click(function(evt){
       if(evt.target.class == "dropdown")
          return;
$('.dropdown').toggleClass('open');
    $(".open").on("click", function(){
        $('.dropdown a').attr('href','http://example.com');
        $('.dropdown a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
    });
    if($(evt.target).closest('.dropdown').length)
          return;             
        $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
        $('.dropdown a').attr('href','#');
        $('.dropdown a').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
});
```

and this is my html code:

```
<li class="menu-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">dropdown</a>
    <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">page</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldn't solve this problem but for my case i use hover for expand menu and click for open page.
and in mobile mode i disable hover and only expand with click

```
(function($) {
    function mediaSize() {
        if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        $('.dropdown a').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
        } else {
            $('.dropdown a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
            $('li.dropdown').mouseover(function(){
                $(this).addClass('open');
            });
            $('li.dropdown').mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('open');
            });
        }
    };
  mediaSize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', mediaSize, false);  
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below snippet.

```
    $('body').on('click',(function(){
            $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
            $('.dropdown a').attr('href','#');
            $('.dropdown a').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
      });   
    $('.dropdown').on('click' ,function(){
        $(this).addClass('open');     
    });

 $(".dropdown.open").on("click", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            location.href = 'http://example.com';
        });
```

or you could do

```
$('.dropdown').on('click' ,function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('open')) 
           location.href = 'http://example.com';  
        else
         $(this).addClass('open');  
    });
```

if you want to open in new window use window.open(url). Hope this helps

Comment: dosn't work. i add body click for remove the 'open' class after it opens but it remove that class at first and 'open' class dosn't add at all

Comment: use e.stopPropagation().  `$('.dropdown').on('click' ,function(e){ 
       e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass('open');     
    });`

Comment: this exactly my problem. i want only when drop down is open go to external link but in your example and my problem after drop down open and close again the external link remain

Comment: tnx but this is not i want. i don't explain good. this is a navbar that both parent and child have page. i want when click on parent, it open and when it is open click on it open it's page. i want only when drop down is open it's link to example.com